# auto-install jdk7 using jenkins failed

Tags: java, jenkins, vagrant, java-7

I configured Jenkins to install jdk7 automatically from java.sun.com as follows:

[jenkins configuration](https://www.dropbox.com/s/13c5s4myi2ig0ep/jdk7.JPG?dl=0)

[image]

and when i run it, it shows me this error:

```
.
.
.
jdk1.7.0_80/db/bin/derby_common.bat
jdk1.7.0_80/db/bin/startNetworkServer.bat
jdk1.7.0_80/db/bin/startNetworkServer
jdk1.7.0_80/db/bin/setNetworkServerCP.bat
jdk1.7.0_80/db/bin/stopNetworkServer
jdk1.7.0_80/db/README-JDK.html
jdk1.7.0_80/db/NOTICE
jdk1.7.0_80/README.html
jdk1.7.0_80/THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
tar: jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘../libjsig.so’: Protocol error
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
ERROR: Failed to install JDK. Exit code=2
```

Any thoughts? I would really appreciate any way of help.

Comment: You are missing some key information in the question. What is the OS?  What is the jenkin user? Does it have permission to write where ever it is trying?  The error message looks doubtful from standard linux. Is this a VM? (virtualbox ?)

Comment: @Jayan in fact im using vagrant and provision script to install and configure tools inside ubuntu 14.04 box, here is all my [conf file](https://github.com/imad-bouhamidi/vagrant-docker-jenkins-jhipster)

Comment: Please  change  tags appropriately.   Vagrant or virtualbox  may be more relevant  than jenkins etc...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Comment: I am facing it too